ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open Dockerfile: no such file or directory
I am new to docker and i already checked the posts on stackoverflow but i cant resolve my issue:
my file dir:
 Directory of C:\Users\HP\Desktop\nocom2

05/15/2024  12:06 PM    <DIR>          .
05/15/2024  12:06 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/25/2022  05:57 AM             5,320 ad_bot.py
07/25/2022  05:57 AM                68 ad_site.Dockerfile
07/25/2022  05:57 AM             1,089 docker-compose.yml
07/25/2022  05:57 AM             1,176 dockerfile.Dockerfile
07/25/2022  05:57 AM               144 index.html
07/25/2022  05:57 AM    <DIR>          Myst
07/25/2022  05:57 AM             1,790 README.md
07/25/2022  05:57 AM             1,184 requirements.txt
07/25/2022  05:57 AM    <DIR>          venv
               7 File(s)         10,771 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  10,078,896,128 bytes free

This is the project from github and in readme.txt it says to run this command:
Docker build -t ad_bot .
When i try i get this error:
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)  docker:default
2024/05/15 12:12:25 http2: server: error reading preface from client //./pipe/docker_engine: file has already been close[+] Building 0.1s (1/1) FINISHED                                                                         docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                 0.0s
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open Dockerfile: no such file or directory

I am already in right directory. Should i change name of dockerfile?

It's canonically named just Dockerfile with no prefix or extension.

@DavidMaze I already renamed it to Dockerfile but that didnt do anything. Is it because the extension is .Dockerfile and not just file

@DaniloVracar as David already mentioned, the file has no extension.

When you run docker build -t ad_bot ., Docker looks in the current directory for a file named Dockerfile.
If your Dockerfile is named something else you need to specify it using the -f or --file option.
In your case, you have two Dockerfiles: ad_site.Dockerfile and dockerfile.Dockerfile. To build an image using one of these files, you would need to specify the file name
docker build -t ad_bot -f ad_site.Dockerfile .
or
docker build -t ad_bot -f dockerfile.Dockerfile .
or would rename your Dockerfile to just Dockerfile. Then you could build your image with the command docker build -t ad_bot .

The same error happened to me, in my case the directory was just wrong. I should be in the cd directory
'C:\users\user\onedrive\documents\docker\course files\app\app\'
but it was giving an error because I was trying to create it in a directory where my files were not located, especially the dockerfile file!
So if it helps, check if you are in the correct directory.
